# C++ Qt, one SQL INSERT query takes too long

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I am developing a window application for online text editing for my university class and I want to implement document revisions system (every time user adds or removes text I save this event in order to back up to some moment in time if necessary). Firstly I tried to save it to Sqlite database table right on the spot server received signal from client. But that decision freezed performance too much, even making savings once per second didn't help too much.

I figured out one call to QSqlQuery::exec() takes 100-200 ms time overhead. I am quite in dispair and don't know any better alternative.
Any recommendation would be totally helpful.
The code I use is listed below.

```
class QueryInsertInto{
        QString m_queryString;
    public:
        QueryInsertInto(const char * const & tableName,
                                     const std::initializer_list<const char *> & columns,
                                     const size_t & totalValues = 1)
        : m_queryString(QString("INSERT INTO %1 (").arg(tableName)){
        Qext::String::appendCommaSeparatedList(m_queryString, columns);
        m_queryString += ") VALUES ";
        QString valueTemplate = "(";
        Qext::String::appendCommaSeparatedValue(
            valueTemplate, columns.size(), "?"
        );
        valueTemplate += ')';
        Qext::String::appendCommaSeparatedValue(
            m_queryString, totalValues, valueTemplate
        );
        m_queryString += ';';
    }


        template <typename TQVariantsContainer>
        QSqlQuery tryExecQuery(const QSqlDatabase & db, TQVariantsContainer && values);

        QSqlQuery tryExecQuery(const QSqlDatabase & db,
                               const std::initializer_list<QVariant> & values);
    };

    template<typename TQVariantsContainer>
    QSqlQuery QueryInsertInto::tryExecQuery(const QSqlDatabase & db,
                               TQVariantsContainer && values){
        QSqlQuery query(db);
        if (!query.prepare(m_queryString)){
            throw MessageException(
                QString("query prepare failure (%1)")
                    .arg(query.lastError().text()).toStdString()
            );
        }
        for (const auto & value : values){
            query.addBindValue(value);
        }
        QTime time;
        time.start();
        if (!query.exec()){
            throw MessageException(
                QString("query exec failure (%1)")
                    .arg(query.lastError().text()).toStdString()
            );
        }
        int elapsed { time.elapsed() };
        QLOG("query exec elapsed ms-> " << elapsed); // reports 100-200 ms
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Don't save on the main UI thread.  Use a queue and background thread to do the saves.

Comment: Dont prepare the query for every request

Comment: Well, thank you guys. I've always avoided multithreaded programming and never used it before. However this did worked out =)